# How to sort ll output

Tags: ls, filenames, sort, hp-ux

`ll` returns this result:

```
51380224 Aug  3 08:23 tig_10.d1
51380224 Aug  3 08:18 tig_10.d10
51380224 Aug  3 08:20 tig_10.d11
51380224 Aug  3 08:23 tig_10.d12
51380224 Aug  3 08:21 tig_10.d13
51380224 Jul 31 12:06 tig_10.d14
131072 Jul 31 12:06 tig_10.d15
51380224 Aug  3 08:15 tig_10.d2
51380224 Aug  2 23:08 tig_10.d3
51380224 Aug  2 14:24 tig_10.d4
51380224 Aug  2 14:24 tig_10.d5
51380224 Aug  3 08:21 tig_10.d6
51380224 Aug  3 08:22 tig_10.d7
51380224 Aug  3 08:13 tig_10.d8
51380224 Aug  3 08:20 tig_10.d9
```

Been unsuccessful to list the files like this

```
51380224 Aug  3 08:23 tig_10.d1
51380224 Aug  3 08:15 tig_10.d2
51380224 Aug  2 23:08 tig_10.d3
51380224 Aug  2 14:24 tig_10.d4
51380224 Aug  2 14:24 tig_10.d5
51380224 Aug  3 08:21 tig_10.d6
51380224 Aug  3 08:22 tig_10.d7
51380224 Aug  3 08:13 tig_10.d8
51380224 Aug  3 08:20 tig_10.d9
51380224 Aug  3 08:18 tig_10.d10
51380224 Aug  3 08:20 tig_10.d11
51380224 Aug  3 08:23 tig_10.d12
51380224 Aug  3 08:21 tig_10.d13
51380224 Jul 31 12:06 tig_10.d14
131072 Jul 31 12:06 tig_10.d15
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: What is the command alias `ll` set for? Please post the output of `alias ll` so we can figure out what's messing with the sorting of the output.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`ls` will re-sort the filenames you give it (or the current directory, if you don't) itself; one way around this would be to give it the filenames separately:

```
ls -l *.d? ; ls -l *.d??
```

Or, since you appear to have an alias/function to do a long listing:

```
ll *.d?; ll *.d??
```

Comment: Note that GNU `ls` has a `-U` option to disable the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your `ll` is. `ll` is a commonly given alias to `ls -l`, but that doesn't look like it.

In any case, that particular output could be sorted in the order you want with GNU `sort` and its *version* sort applied to the 5th column and over:

```
ll | sort -bVk5
```

If  `ll` is somehow an alias to `ls` and your `ls` is GNU `ls`, then that `ls` also has a *version* sort enabled with `-v`.

With the `zsh` shell, you can have its globs sorted in a similar fashion with the `numericglobsort` option or the `(n)` glob qualifier. So if your `ll` command can get the list of file names as argument and doesn't do any further sorting itself, you could do (in `zsh`, and `zsh` only):

```
ll *(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sort`:

```
$ ls -lghFG | sort -n -td -k2
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d1
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d3
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d4
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d5
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d6
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d7
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d8
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d9
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d10
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d11
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d12
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d13
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d14
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 Aug  3 09:43 tig_10.d15
```

This will use the letter `d` as a delimiter and sort the output numerically on the field 2 so there could be issues if your filenames contain the letter `d`.

To meet your requirement of using `ll` (which is an alias) you could do (not recommended:

```
alias ll='ls -lghFG | sort -n -td -k2'
```

Answer (score 0):

from `man`,

`ll -v`

- -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within the text